# Google Chrome --allow-running-insecure-content does not work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-flags

The **Google Chrome** flag `--allow-running-insecure-content` does not work. I have confirmed that the executable is in fact running with this flag by seeing the command line args in the `chrome://version/` URL where it is clearly reflected.

When I visit our internal **Github** enterprise instance, which is on `HTTPS` I cannot see our **TeamCity** build status icons as the URL is on `HTTP`. We have these icons in our *README.md* and I end up with these `(blocked:mixed-content)` errors in the *Dev Tools / Network* tab.

[image]

```
Google Chrome: 54.0.2840.99 (Official Build) m (64-bit)
```

Comment: this is more of a statement than a question. However, I too would like to know if there's a solution

Answer (score 7):

I think the documentation is not up to date. The mixed content mode was made stricter according to [chromium.org](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=190728). You should be able to solve the problem in any of the two ways below using multiple flags.

```
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://domain1.com,http://domain2.com --user-data-dir=/test/only/dir
```

Or don't enforce the same-origin policy (not recommended).

```
--disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content (add --user-data-dir=/test/only/dir if needed)
```